# Class not found using namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, zend-framework2

With ZF1 when i create the database connection string it works without any issue. But in ZF2 database adapter seems BUG never works, it gives always the following:

Error:

```
[Fri Nov 02 13:26:25 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Application\\Controller\\Zend\\Db\\Adapter\\Adapter' not found in /var/www/html/org/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/TestController.php on line 17
```

Code:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
//use Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\PlatformInterface;
//use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
class TestController extends AbstractActionController {
  public function indexAction() {
    $driverArray = array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
    'database' => 'web145',
    'username' => 'web145',
    'password' => 'meandmypassword',
    'host'=>'localhost'
    );
    $adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($driverArray);
    //Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::query('SELECT * FROM `sh_operaor`');
    //var_dump ($adapter->query('SELECT * FROM `sh_operaor`'));
    exit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already used namespace Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter, you should call it like this:

```
$adapter = new Adapter($driverArray);
```

Or you could call it from root namespace start with backslash

```
$adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($driverArray);
```

Comment: And if you want to use the full qualified name, it must start with a backslash \ . If not, PHP looks for a subnamespace `Zend` inside your current namespace.

Comment: You put an extra `Adapter` in your full qualified name example.